# Add GPS waypoint when on the road - what´s on the market?

Tags: gps

A guy from work needs an easy setup when he´s on the road by car. The request is the option where he can press a button that saves location as GPS-stamp. Afterwards he needs it to be visualized in a map. Right now I´m looking into any app that can do the most of this (must be on Android) an hoping to trigger this by a bluetooth device or similiar. Is there something like this on the market?

Comment: That would match the categories [Tracking](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_tracking#group_579) (with manual waypoint adding) or, alternatively, [location memos](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_locationmemos). Take your pick if it should just be a simple stamp, or some other details (notes, photos, …) should be added.

Comment: Gladly! If you find something that fits, please consider to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

After trying out the many solutions (links provided by @Izzy) I landed on this one:
[Map Marker (iOS and Android)](https://www.mapmarker.app/)
Many features and great documentation. Help the devs behind by upgrading to premium -they deserve it.

**Solutuion 2 - with physical button**

I bought a Flic button, created an IFTTT acccount and created an applet that adds longitude/latitude into a Google Sheet. The Google Sheet works dynamically (don´t forget to publish it) and from there you can create a live webmap with https://www.gpsvisualizer.com/. Don´t forget to donate to the guy!

Comment: Please accept this as an answer, as doing so will help others who read this question in future.